# dismissViewControllerAnimated not working in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios9, presentviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` subclass called `NewsViewController` which has a completion block property that is called from a button action. The controller is set up and presented in another view controller like this:

```
newsViewController.completionBlock = ^{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
};

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newsViewController];
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In iOS 10 this all works fine, however in iOS 9 the view is not being dismissed. If I put a breakpoint there it does get hit.

I have tried the following without success:

**Called it from the main thread (both synchronously and asynchronously)**

I have tried it using GCD like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

I have also tried it by putting the dismissal call into a method and then calling

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(dismissModalView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

I don't actually thing the issue is the thread since a call to `[NSThread isMainThread]` from within the completion block returns YES.

**Calling it with a delay**

```
[self performSelector:@selector(dismissModalView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

**Calling dismiss on another view controller**

I have tried calling it on `navigationController`, `self.presentedViewController` and `self.presentingViewController`.

**Calling dismiss directly from NewsViewController**

In the button action where the completion block was called I called `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]` directly.

Btw. just for fun I tried calling the dismiss method from the completion block of the `presentViewController` method and there it did get dismissed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally located the problem and it was quite unexpected. The thing is that the `NewsViewController` is presented over my login view controller. This controller allows the user to use Touch ID to log in so it requests the Touch ID prompt in its `viewDidAppear` method. Apparently, this messes with the dismissal of the presented view, and seemingly only in iOS 9 (well, maybe not only, but it seems to work fine in iOS 10).

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
newsViewController.completionBlock = ^{
   [self performSelector:@selector(Dismiss) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
};

 -(void)Dismiss
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    }];
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what I would accomplish with this. Using your code I would present the `NewsViewController` again after dismissing it. This is not what I want at all and it wouldn't solve my problem anyway (not being able to dismiss in the first place).

Comment: You need to dismiss it on completion then only write dismiss without anything in completion block.

Comment: Your code would give me an infinite cycle. In the completion block you are presenting the same view controller again. So when the view is dismissed it will be presented again.

Comment: As you may see from my original question I had already tried that approach. But anyway, I have located the root of the issue now.